# STM32 - several PWM signals with different multiplied frequencies

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pwm, timer

Is it possible using STM32 F to generate several PWM signals with one timer, but each channel has different frequency (multiplied of two) of PWM? All signals must be synchronized, so I need to use only one timer. Each channel should have different duty cycle.

Comment: You can have a different duty cycle on each channel, but not a different frequency.

Comment: I know that I can have a different duty cycle and I know I don't have totally random frequencies on each channel, but is it possible that each channel has multiplied frequency? For example CH1-240Hz, CH2-120Hz, CH3-60Hz and CH4-30Hz ?

Comment: Can't you use different timers and sync the timers?

Comment: @Adam Please ask a specific question, "Is it possible" questions are off topic. Edit your question.